# How to generate a unique number between a range in mysql

Tags: mysql, concurrency, sequence

I have a question regarding the mysql. Here's the scenario

I have a table say merchant, it has the following fields

```
merid , mer_cusno_start, mer_cusno_end, ..
```

Now I have a table to store the customers of each merchant and it has the fields

```
cusid, cus_merid, cus_cusno,email...
```

When a new customer is signing up with a merchant, I want to generate the **cus_cusno**  which should be in the range specified by that merchant( between **mer_cusno_start - mer_cusno_end**) .

No two customers should have the same **cus_cusno** for the same merchant, ( customers of different merchant can have same **cus_cusno**). The number need not be sequential. But should come between the range.

How can it be implemented in mysql with no concurrency issues considering the fact that multiple customers may be trying to sign up with the same merchant simultaneously ?.

Thanks in advance

Sandheep

Comment: Why don't you just link the customer to merchant with a foreign key in the customer table to `merid`? That's how it's usually done.

Comment: I'll try to find a suitable answer for your question, but please take my advice: name your fields with understandable names like merchantId,merchantCustomerNo, customer_id whatever. I had the unlucky experience of working on a database created by hasty people it was a nightmare and trust me it will be great for you when you will have 5-6 applications under support.

Comment: First thought is to have a UNIQUE INDEX in table `customers`, on `(cus_merid, cus_cusno)` to avoid any collisions (two customers having same customerNo with same merchantID).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PHP microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) to add some sequencing into your customer numbers. This way there could be no collisions as long as the clock continues to run.

Alternatively just check to see what the last `cus_cusno` was, and add 1.

Comment: The question has no mention of `PHP`. Why do you recommend using PHP? And how your solution avoids collisions?

Comment: He can't add 1 to cus_cusno, because the last customer my be signed up to a different merchant, if I understand his question correctly.